# Frequency of vectors inside list

Tags: r, list, count

Let's say I have a list

```
test <- list(c(1, 2, 3), c(2, 4, 6), c(1, 5, 10), c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 5, 10), c(1, 2, 3))
```

and I need to count all of these vectors so the desired output should looks like:

```
Category    Count
1, 2, 3      3
2, 4, 6      1
1, 5, 10     2
```

Is there any simple way in R how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just paste and use `table`, i.e.

```
as.data.frame(table(sapply(test, paste, collapse = ' ')))
```

which gives,

> ```
>     Var1 Freq
> 1  1 2 3    3
> 2 1 5 10    2
> 3  2 4 6    1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The function `unique()` can work on a list. For counting one can use `identical()`:

```
test <- list(c(1, 2, 3), c(2, 4, 6), c(1, 5, 10), c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 5, 10), c(1, 2, 3))
Lcount <- function(xx, L) sum(sapply(L, identical, y=xx))
sapply(unique(test), FUN=Lcount, L=test)
unique(test)
```

The result as data.frame:

```
result <- data.frame(
 Set=sapply(unique(test), FUN=paste0, collapse=','),
 count= sapply(unique(test), FUN=Lcount, L=test)
)
result
# > result
#      Set count
# 1  1,2,3     3
# 2  2,4,6     1
# 3 1,5,10     2
```